# When setting up Kubernetes, why can't my Gitlab GUI see the Helm Tiller application?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

when I recently tried to use Gitlab Auto DevOps to Kubernetes, my Gitlab GUI cannot see the Helm Tiller application.
Why?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you using helm-v3?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason could be that you are using [Helm 3](https://helm.sh/blog/helm-3-released/). The Tiller doesn't exist on Helm 3.

> The internal implementation of Helm 3 has changed considerably from Helm 2. The most apparent change is the removal of Tiller.